# Pesquisa Exata no Apache Solr

Tags: apache-solr

Olá. Estou realizando uma pesquisa no Apache Solr mas ele me retorna vários itens que estão fora da busca.

Por exemplo, digamos que eu tenha três itens, Tablet Samsung 7", Tablet Samsung 10.1" e TV Samsung, ao pesquisar apenas por TV Samsung ele retorna junto o Tablet Samsung.

Como seria a query para buscar Tablet Samsung 10.1 e só retornar este item e não retornar os outros tablets e nem a TV?

```
http://site.com/collection1/select?q=*tv%20samsung*&start=0&rows=16&sort=name+asc&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=cat_id&facet.field=atributos&facet.field=manu_id&fq=price:[0.01+TO+*]
```

Comment: Para melhorar sua pergunta. Por favor, adicione também seu código.

Answer (score 0):

A solução é simples, basta adicionar os seguintes parâmetros na URL de busca:

```
&defType=edismax&mm=100%25&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true
```